# I'm receiving "Host can't be null" error when updating database in a .NET7 project with Postgresql database

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd like to ask you for some help. I have a .NET7 project connected to the Postgresql database system, which works perfectly in Visual Studio on Windows, but there are some issues when I open it in any IDE (Visual Studio, Rider) on my new Macbook. When I hit the command "dotnet ef database update", I receive an error "Host can't be null"

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Host can't be null
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.PostProcessAndValidate()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.SetupDataSource()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CloneWith(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlRelationalConnection.CloneWith(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Host can't be null
```

I checked my connection string multiple times and it's correctly attached, my dotnet ef version is 7.0.11 and all NuGet Packages are also compatible with that version of EF:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.15" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="7.0.11" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.11">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.11" />
      <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.5.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.5.1">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I've also tried to build a simple project with database with same version of EF and packages and "dotnet ef database update" command worked perfectly there.

This is my AppDbContext.cs:

```
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {   
        //...some code

        protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        } 

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>
                ("BaggageTagsSequence").StartsAt(1).IncrementsBy(1).HasMax(999999).IsCyclic();
        }
    }
```

...and I don't know if it's necessary, but here is also Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<QueryExecutionService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/errors/{0}");

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

try
{
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    await AppDbSeedData.SeedAll(context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
}

app.Run();
```

So now, I don't have any ideas, does anybody have a clue where there might be a problem?

Comment: could you try adding code to get the connection string vlaue to see it is returning the correct or not `_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")`. try to hardcode connection string temporary. have you checked the database is accessible from the macbook? Since you mentioned a `Program.cs` file, make sure that the service configuration for `AddDbContext` is using the same connection string name, `"DefaultConnection"`, and that it matches what is in your appsettings.

Comment: yes I made `Console.WriteLine("DefaultConnection")` to see if correct connection string was attached either in `Program.cs` file or in `AppDbContext.cs` file and it was correct. I've also checked my database connection using `psql` command in terminal and I've been able to successfully access the database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a missing 'Host' attribute in your `appsettings.json` file

It should look something like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Host=your_host; Port=your_port; User Id=postgres; Password=your_password; Database=your_database_name"
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, but this was a first thing I've checked :/